# Native Query using a specific scheme

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I need to perform a specific query that can't be done using HSQL syntax - [see my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426601/nested-select-in-query-annotation).

So I need to do this with a native query, which works just fine:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT tag FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tag FROM dev.CustomerTag)t WHERE similarity(tag, ?1) > 0 ORDER BY similarity(tag, ?1)", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findByName(String searchQuery);
```

The problem, however, is that the database scheme (in this case `dev`) is hardcoded, but I need to be able to configure it in my application's property file.

This is no problem in conventional queries since they care about the `@Table(scheme="dev")` annotation or, in my case,  the `hibernate.default_schema`  configuration in the context file.

How can I inject the scheme in this query or how can I teach spring to use the default scheme?

Comment: @JensSchauder Why do you think the distinct is superfluous? I have a 1:m connection between the tables, so if two customers have the same tag, it is stored multiple times, thus queried multiple times. (Not an ideal structure for big databases, but good enough for mine). Can you give me an example for a more efficient query which returns the same result set?

Comment: Sorry, misread the query. I thought it was of the form `... where x in (subselect)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always implement a [custom repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations) and dynamically create your sql string, adding the necessary schema.